what do notifications like N1,N2,N6,M1,M2,M6,eps-1,eps-2,eps-6,eps-x,eps-y,eps-s,k1,k2,k6 mean in Genlam Software
Question :
What do notifications like N1,N2,N6,M1,M2,M6,eps-1,eps-2,eps-6,eps-x,eps-y,eps-s,k1,k2,k6 mean in Genlam Software?

Does that software come with a help file or user guide?
